# How to navigate "Shared with Me" folders in the Sidebar?

Tags: google-apps-script

Developing an apps script that involves allowing the user to navigate through the folders and files in Google Drive from the sidebar.

We would also like to allow users to view folders and contained files in the "Shared with Me" section, but so far not able to discover how this can be facilitated.

The Drive Service page
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/ mentions a number of methods, including:

`getFolders()` - Gets a collection of all folders in the user's Drive.

However there is no mention of viewing the folders and files which are "Shared with Me". I have noticed that some apps are capable of allowing users to navigate through these files as well (though I can't say I recall seeing any Google Apps-Scrips/Add-Ons that have this functionality).

Answer (score 5):

They say that "Shared with me" isn't actually a folder but a filter (http://alicekeeler.com/2015/09/03/google-drive-shared-with-me-is-a-filter-not-a-folder/) so a similar approach can probably applied in your case: you would like to only show those files and/or folders whose owners are different from the active user:

```
 function myFunction() {
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var fileOwnerEmail = files.next().getOwner().getEmail();
    if (fileOwnerEmail !== userEmail) {
      Logger.log(fileOwnerEmail);
    }
  }
}
```

UPD
Found a better way:

```
function usingSearch() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
    'sharedWithMe');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName() + file.getOwner().getEmail());
  }

}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)